# Получить все переменные, участвующие в файле шаблона smarty

Tags: php, шаблоны, smarty

Встретился с задачей, что нужно написать php код, обрабатывающий, разработанные до меня, шаблоны smarty. Документацию прошлые разработчики не оставили. Теперь мучаюсь с тем, как узнать все переменные и их структуру, которые используются в файле шаблона. Шаблон большой, поэтому в ручную всё искать не хочется.

**В итоге вопрос:** Как получить полный список всех переменных в шаблоне smarty, которые я должен в этот шаблон загрузить?

Заранее спасибо

Для шаблонов использую smarty3, php7.4

Пример шаблона:

```
{if $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="01"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Адыгея"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="02"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Башкирия"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="03"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Бурятская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="04"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Алтай"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="05"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Дагестан"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="06"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ингушская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="07"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Кабардино-Балкарская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="08"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Калмыкия"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="09"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Карачаево-Черкесская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="10"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Карелия"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="11"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Коми"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="12"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Марий-Эл"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="13"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Мордовская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="14"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Саха (Якутия)"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="15"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Северная Осетия"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="16"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Татарстан"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="17"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Тува"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="18"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Удмуртская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="19"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Хакасия"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="20"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Чеченская Республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="21"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Чувашская республика"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="22"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Алтайский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="23"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Краснодарский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="24"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Красноярский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="25"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Приморский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="26"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ставропольский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="27"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Хабаровский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="28"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Амурская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="29"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Архангельская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="30"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Астраханская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="31"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Белгородская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="32"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Брянская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="33"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Владимирская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="34"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Волгоградская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="35"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Вологодская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="36"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Воронежская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="37"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ивановская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="38"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Иркутская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="39"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Калининградская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="40"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Калужская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="41"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Камчатский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="42"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Кемеровская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="43"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Кировская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="44"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Костромская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="45"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Курганская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="46"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Курская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="47"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ленинградская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="48"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Липецкая область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="49"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Магаданская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="50"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Московская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="51"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Мурманская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="52"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Нижегородская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="53"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Новгородская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="54"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Новосибирская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="55"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Омская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="56"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Оренбургская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="57"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Орловская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="58"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Пензенская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="59"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Пермский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="60"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Псковская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="61"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ростовская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="62"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Рязанская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="63"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Самарская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="64"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Саратовская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="65"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Сахалинская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="66"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Свердловская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="67"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Смоленская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="68"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Тамбовская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="69"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Тверская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="70"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Томская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="71"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Тульская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="72"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Тюменская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="73"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ульяновская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="74"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Челябинская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="75"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Забайкальский край"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="76"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ярославская область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="77"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Город Москва"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="78"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Город Санкт-Петербург"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="79"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Еврейская автономная область"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="83"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ненецкий автономный округ"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="86"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ханты-Мансийский АО"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="87"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Чукотский автономный округ"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="89"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Ямало-Ненецкий АО"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="91"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Республика Крым"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="92"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Г.Севастополь"}
{elseif $doc.dokument.documentinfo.consignee.adres.adrrf.regionCode=="99"}{assign var="regionConsignee" value="Иные территории, включая город и космодром Байконур"}
{/if}
```

Comment: ищите все вхождения `{$...}` в шаблоне. других вариантов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Код не проверял, возможны очепятки. Если набрал без ошибок, то должен найти все файлы внутри папки `"path/to/tpl_folder"`, прочитать каждый файл и выбрать из каждого файла встречающиеся переменные.

```
<?php
$templateFolder = "path/to/tpl_folder";  

$re = '/\$[\w\d_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\d_]+)|(?:\[\'[^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*\'\])|(?:\["[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"\]))*/mi';

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($templateFolder));

$variables = array(); 

foreach ($iterator as $file) {

    if ($file->isDir()){ 
        continue;
    }

    $path = $file->getPathname(); 
    $contents = file_get_contents($path);
    preg_match_all($re, $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
    $variables[] = $matches;
}

var_export($variables);
?>
```

Ссылка на регулярку: https://regex101.com/r/JxKUkQ/2

Comment: дебаг показыает, какие переменные переданы в шаблон.
автор же решает обратную задачу. у него есть шаблоны, и надо сформировать нужные данные под них

Comment: Тогда там вообще легко, регуляркой собрать.

Comment: @DiD тогда буду признателен как это сделать через регулярку. А иначе альтернатива моя будет программно пройтись по тексту шаблоны и вычленить всё, что похоже на обращение к переменным в шаблоне, а это не очень удобное решение.

Comment: @FlashSpoker, добавьте в вопрос часть какого-нибудь шаблона, чтобы тестировать регулярку на вашем коде.

Comment: @DiD добавил, надеюсь, получится через регулярку. Буду очень признателен

Comment: @FlashSpoker Смотрите, вот эта регулярка вроде бы в примере шаблона находит все совпадения и даже больше https://regex101.com/r/JxKUkQ/2  Попробую оформить с ней код

Comment: @FlashSpoker изменил ответ, этот код должно быть найдёт все переменные. Если найдёт не всё, напишите, добавим в регулярку что не нашлось.

Comment: @DiD спасибо большое. Помогло. Не знаю как отметить комментарий, как ответ, поэтому если хотите - оставьте ответ, отмечу как правильный. Stackoverflow должен знать своих героев)